# Website Mortgage & Insurance Calculator = Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, joomla

I'm working on a website with Joomla for a small financial services company. I need to implement a simple mortgage and insurance calculator and I have no clue where to start. With Joomla, I can create custom HTML modules and implement them wherever I want. I looked through other sites and Javascript looks like the language of choice.

Is Javascript the only way to build the calculator!?

Is there ANY way I can do this using html!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need a language that can do the math for you. HTML wouldn't be able to pull that off. I found a heap of Joomla extensions similar to this one... http://archive.extensions.joomla.org/extensions/financial/taxes-a-mortgages/2237

However... I would recommend just writing your own jQuery using a method similar to the one on this blog... http://www.issackelly.com/blog/2009/01/11/Simple_JQuery_Mortgage_Calculato/

Comment: Ohhh awesome! Looks super easy thank you!

Comment: I hate the extensions because they mess up your CSS style, as in pure aesthetics wise, but the jQuery one looks cool because I sitll have artistic control. Again thanks!

Comment: Ya, it's always better to roll your own if you can. Good luck!